# How to render Markdown reactively from localStorage?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, markdown, vuex, vuejs3

I can get `markdown` in `string` format from `localStorage`, transform it with `marked` function into `markdown` and assign it to `reactive state` so it can be rendered in my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="about-info">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div v-html="state.content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import {reactive} from "vue";
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
import marked from "marked";

const state = reactive({
    content: DOMPurify(marked(localStorage.content)) || "",
})
</script>
```

This works as long as `localStorage.content` is not `undefined`. Usually `state` can handle `undefined` values with the `or operator` (`||`). Unfortunately `marked` function can't handle `undefined` and throws errors:

```
Error: marked(): input parameter is undefined or null
Uncaught (in promise) Error: marked(): input parameter is undefined or null
```

My only solution to this is to get `store.content` from an `ajax.request` every time the page loads but that makes my component use server requests, which I'm trying to circumvent with `localStorage`.

I've tried rendering `DOMPurify/marked` in the component like so:

```
<div v-html="DOMPurify(marked(state.content))"></div>
```

but it renders the function code instead:

```
function DOMPurify(root) { return createDOMPurify(root); }
```

Is there any way to get `markdown` from `localStorage` without `marked` throwing those errors if it's `undefined`?

Comment: Try `content: localStorage.content ? DOMPurify(marked(localStorage.content)) : ""`

Comment: Damn, that works! Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: I think the problem is not Vue specific, it depends on the context, which maybe you can explain better than me.

Comment: Short circuit is in wrong place, likely should be `marked(localStorage.content || ''))` . It's  unclear why this has to do with reactivity. You set it only once, and it likely doesn't need to be `reactive` at all.

Comment: @EstusFlask What if `localStorage` is cleared upon `refresh`? Then your `ls` is empty when the components tries to load it and you have to get the content from an `ajax request`, which only works with reactive variables.

Comment: What is "refresh" in tech terms? Page reload? "which only works with reactive variables" - it's unclear what you mean. You probably try to solve a problem that doesn't exist in the first place. If you wrap a variable that never changes with `reactive`, this doesn't change anything, only adds overhead.

Comment: A variable acquired from an `ajax request` does change